# Laravel jobs on custom queue replace by "default" queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on queue and I found custom queue won't be run.

I run `php artisan queue:work --queue=emails` and I dispatch queue `MyJob::dispatch()->onQueue('emails')->delay(now()->addMinutes(1))`.

In database table `jobs` will be like this:

| id | queue | payload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emails | ... |

After 1 minute:

| id | queue | payload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | default | ... |

It seems queue `emails` is processed, and remove from database. Then create another job for queue `default` with the same payload and job queue `default` will never run except I run `php artisan queue:work --queue=emails,default`

In Laravel documentation not mention to always run queue `default`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#specifying-the-connection-queue

Is it correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem of duplicate rows occurs when I set `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `database` in `.env` file like this:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

I solved the problem by keep value of `QUEUE_CONNECTION` as default of Laravel `sync`

And add `database` to command like this:

```
php artisan queue:work database --queue=my_custom_queue_name
```